# Is it possible to inverse a sum of exponents

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

I have a problem, I need to inverse a sum of exponents. Is it possible?

I have this function

$y = 0.84826731\times e^{-1.10973369x} + 0.17939312\times e^{-0.1902204x} + 0.02965983\times e^{-0.02028059x}$

and I would like to get to

$$x = f(y)$$

The ranges in which I need `x = f(y)`,  is y between `(0,1)`, which results in x in the range of `~(0,100)`

It does not have to be 100% correct. 99.9% will also be ok.

Thanks.

Comment: If $x$ can go down as low as $0$ (or very close to $0$), then $y$ can go as high as $1.05732026$ (or very close to it). And of $x$ can range up to $100$ (or close to $100$) then $y$ can only go as low as $0.0039029585\ldots$ (or close to that). So is there a mistake with your ranges on $x$ and $y$, or are you only giving approximate intervals?

Comment: @alex.jordan the range of y that I need is y>0 and y<1, I need a method that for each y I will know what x to use. and the y's that I will use are lower than 1 and larger than 0. this approximate x values between 0 to 100.

Comment: If $y$ can go down to $0$, then $x$ can go up to $\infty$. Stopping $x$ at $100$ seems arbitrary. I think my answer still works for $y$ really close to $0$. The function is essentially $0.02965983e^{-0.02028059x}$ for the larger $x$-values that lead to the really small $y$-values. And inverting this approximation is trivial. For roughly $y\in(0.02,1)$ I think you may need to resort to "numerical" methods. Instead of some formula, you have some algorithm to solve for $x$ given any $y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is very large, then $x$ must be negative, and the first term is dominant. So $x\approx\frac{-1}{1.10973369}\ln\mathopen{}\left(\frac{y}{0.84826731}\right)\mathclose{}$.

If $y$ is very small, then $x$ must be positive, and the last term is dominant. So $x\approx\frac{-1}{0.02028059}\ln\mathopen{}\left(\frac{y}{0.02965983}\right)\mathclose{}$.

I guess you can do some numerical experiments to see how large is large enough and how small is small enough for these approximations. A purely visual inspection of some graphs suggests to me that these are decent for $y>10$ and $y<0.02$. For $y$ in the middle region, you have other approximation options like numerical solution from Newton's method.

Comment: I should have wrote the ranges... I added them now

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use taylor series to approximate $y$ in form of one exponential and then use logarithm both side to get inverse.